# Is there a Control Theory site?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've tried to find a section about control systems in here but no luck. My question is why there is no control system section in here.

Comment: Check out [area51.SE].  That is the site to propose new SE sites.  In fact there *was* as [Control Systems](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44855/control-systems) proposal, but it was closed because it couldn't get enough support to be considered a viable proposal.

Comment: What aspect of control theory are you looking for specifically?  Signal processing (http://dsp.stackexchange.com) covers a lot of the basics.

Comment: (in terms of LTI systems, transforms, filtering, etc.)  I don't know whether implementation issues are specifically off-topic, but I think you could probably stretch most questions to fit there.

Comment: Incidentally, if it's programming regarding control theory, eg [Creating a MIMO (multiple input multiple output) transfer function system without hardcoding the number of inputs and outputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949664/creating-a-mimo-multiple-input-multiple-output-transfer-function-system-withou) then they can be on topic at stack overflow

Comment: Alternatively, if you're trying to get some help with some linear algebra (or whatever you're using) then [math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com/) is an option...

Comment: @psubsee2003, thanks for the link.

Comment: I don't want to be banned again because of off-topic issues. I'm not really sure if DSP section will be appropriate for some control theories even in math. Yes, linear algebra is heavily used however, sometimes the context plays an essential role.

Comment: @CroCo Can you give a specific example?

Comment: Just as using wave variables theory.

Answer (score 9):

As noted by @psubsee2003 in the comments, [there was a proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44855/control-systems) but it was also closed because it didn't have enough support to be launched.

You can think of restarting the proposal, but chances are great that simply not enough people are actively interested in the subject to support a dedicated Q&A.

@jonsca also suggests https://dsp.stackexchange.com/, which might be suitable for basic questions.

Comment: I fully support this idea. How many supports does it need?

Answer (score 2):

I restarted the proposal [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89119/control-theory). Please join if you would to like to see an active Q&A site for Control Theory.

Comment: deleted as well!